Can I select all items on a specific coordinate of an axis?
I'm VERY new to Blender.
I've looked everywhere for an answer, multiple times, but have not been able to find one.
I'm working with something that is uniform. I want to alter everything on a layer/level, one at a time.
So all of the vertices, edges, faces I want to select have identical Z coordinates. Is it possible to use something, like select similar, to select all vertices, edges, or faces at an exact (or median) axis coordinate?

What I generally do in this situation is:

Turn on ghost mode in the 3D Viewport using the button in its header or (with your mouse cursor over the 3D Viewport) by pressing Alt + Z.
Go into a side orthographic view by clicking one of the Navigation Gizmo’s balls (in your case X or Y).
Use Box Select (press B with your mouse cursor over the 3D Viewport) to select a rectangular area that spans across the mesh sideways, but is very narrow on the Z axis spanning only the vertices you want.


That makes sense. I usually use wireframe, in a similar manner.
I was hoping to do something like select by exact position on the axis. But it's sounding like that might not exist.
I appreciate you answering!
